# User scope with Devise and Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm doing some proof of concepts with Rails. I created a Customer, and apply to it DEVISE.
Everythig works fine, but now i'm trying to logging with a customer and enter directly into his scope.
localhost:3000/customers/1
After this hide the /customers/1 with some word, for example: myProfile.

I'm trying to do the first part with

module ApplicationHelper

protected
    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      #path to redirect
   end
end

I was trying with definitions from routes.rb

```
redirect_to(customers_path)
```

or something like:

```
@customer= Customer.find_by_email(current_customer.email)
redirect_to(customer_path(@customer))
```

But nothing is working yet.

I'm not sure how to send messages to the console of the server (like in Java with some System.out.println) to check the contents...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? i can't understand the problem from this information. By the title I think you're dealing with scopes, by the first part of the question I think you're trying to redirect or slug urls, and by the last part I feel like you aren't fully understanding what kinds of things go in the routes.rb file. Please provide clearer information so we can help.

Comment: Sorry... I'm really newbie with rails. The main thing than i'm trying to do is to login with Devise and redirected to the view of the customer logged. localhost:3000/customers/1

Comment: See this, maybe it will help if you haven't solved this problem already. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in